# can not start android service

Tags: android, service

I have calling service like this...

```
startService(new Intent(this,SendMessage.class));
```

this is my service class..

```
public class SendMessage extends Service{
 public void onCreate() {   
      SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
           smsManager.sendTextMessage("+919899709311" , null, "EMERGENCY!!! ", null, null);
      stopSelf(); 

    // override other method
}  
}
```

I have defined my service in manifest as,,,

```
<service  
        android:name="send_data.SendMessage"  
        android:enabled="true" />
```

The problem it is not calling the service,, i have use log.d in service but nothing prints on log..

Comment: Where do you set the onClickListener and implement the onClick methodology for your button?

Comment: onclick is correctly implemented ,, i have checked bu log.d and also by toast

Comment: the mobile is dual sim .. is there is any problem because of that..

Comment: Try overriding onCreate, think that is your problem

Comment: Do you have any other service that extends abstract SendMessage service? If so, you should set that class to intent, otherwise remove abstract word from your service definition.

Comment: I have done whatever u said but nothing works.. :(

Comment: your service definition in android manifest seems wrong to me. Try using your full package name.

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation. The call to

```
startService(new Intent(this, SendMessage.class));
```

> Every call to this method will result in a corresponding call to the target service's onStartCommand(Intent, int, int) method, with the intent given here. This provides a convenient way to submit jobs to a service without having to bind and call on to its interface.

I think you need to override the onStartCommand method.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your manifest file :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```